# Smooth representation of my data

Tags: r, smoothing, microarray

I was directed here from the R community so I guess it's needless to say that I'm working with R :)
So I'm working with array data, resulting in ~950k x-y value pairs per array which I would like to visualise, for example using D3.js. I probably don't have to tell you that I won't be able to plot the entire raw data, that's more than 50MB per array. Also, the data is a bit noisy, which I fixed using smooth.spline() for within the R environment. I was pretty content with the results and so my idea for moving to visualisation with  D3.js was to just take every 20th value and then plot the smoothened line (which is based on the whole raw data set) on top. However, I found out that smooth.spline doesn't give me any equation, and I have yet to find a smoothening algorithm with the same visual accuracy.
Does any of you have an idea how to approach this? Either by finding an equation as a representative of the rest of the data or somehow else?
Just so you get a better idea of what I'm talking about, here is the result of one array.
[image: Here is my data]